# Show testimonials based on post category matching product name

Tags: categories

I have a template section that displays testimonials. The testimonials have been set up as a post type and will be given categories to match product names. Here is the testimonial section:

```
<div class="testimonials-section">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 this-column">
                            <div class="autoplay testimonials-container">
                                <?php
                                    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'testimonials', 'posts_per_page' => 999 );
                                    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                                    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
                                    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                                    echo '<div class="entry-content">';
                                    the_content();
                                    echo '<h3>';
                                    the_field('job_title');
                                    echo ' / ';
                                    the_title();
                                    echo '</h3></div>';
                                    endwhile;
                                    else :
                                        echo wpautop( 'Currently no Testimonials.' );
                                    endif;
                                    wp_reset_query();
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

What I want to do is display testimonials on my single-products.php page if the product name matches the testimonial category.

Here is where I got to but I throw a critical error. Please excuse my ignorance, I am a beginner.

```
<?php 
 $ptitle = $product->get_name();
if (is_testimonial_category()) == $ptitle ) :
echo 'YES, this is where I would add in the above code....';
endif;
 ?>
```

Comment: If Cameron's answer doesn't fix this, can you show us the code for your is_testimonial_category() function please?

Answer (score 1):

You've got an extra closing bracket

`if (is_testimonial_category()) == $ptitle ) :`

should be

`if ( is_testimonial_category() == $ptitle ) :`